# Insert different attributes from keyless table with non-unique records to 2 related tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table "tempImport" with no unique ID column containing several hundreds of records. Lets assume that not all records are unique (i.e. 2+ records may have the exact same values in each column).

I would like to first insert some of the attributes in the tempImport table into table "myTable", which has a PK column with auto-incrementing unique IDs. The repeating rows will be kept-- I do not want to combine them in myTable (from the below example, there will be 3 rows for Samuel Clark and 2 for Faith Hodge in myTable, each with their own unique PK).

Something along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO myTable([name]) SELECT [name] FROM tempImport
```

I would also like to insert the rest of the columns from the tempImport table into another table, "myTableDetails", which contains ID from myTable as FK. As with the previous insert, repeating data will be kept.

```
INSERT INTO myTableDetails([myTableID], [phone],[email],[date],[company]) ...
```

Assume all non-key columns are VARCHAR and key columns are INT datatypes.

Is there a way to do this?

Ideally, I think being able to merge INSERTED from myTable with the other columns in tempImport would solve the issue, although I am not sure how this can be done.

Otherwise, the only option I can think of is to add a PK column to tempImport and add FK in both of the other tables, but that would not be what I'm asking for here.

Here is some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tempImport (
    [name] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [phone] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [email] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [date] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [company] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE myTable (
    [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE myTableDetails (
    [myTableID] INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (myTableID) REFERENCES myTable(ID),
    [phone] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [email] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [date] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [company] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
)

INSERT INTO 
    tempImport([name], [phone], [email], [date], [company]) 
VALUES 
  ('Samuel Clark','1-887-516-2723','example@gmail.com','Apr 9, 2023','Convallis Dolor Ltd'),
  ('Samuel Clark','1-887-516-2723','metus.aenean.sed@yahoo.ca','Apr 9, 2023','Convallis Dolor Ltd'),
  ('Samuel Clark','1-887-516-2723','metus.aenean.sed@yahoo.ca','Apr 9, 2023','Convallis Dolor Ltd'),
  ('Faith Hodge','(903) 877-5281','nunc@aol.com','Mar 18, 2023','Eu Foundation'),
  ('Faith Hodge','(903) 877-5281','nunc@aol.com','Mar 18, 2023','Eu Foundation'),
  ('Fuller Hyde','1-886-712-8325','neque.non@hotmail.org','Jan 21, 2022','In Tempus Associates'),
  ('Yvonne Edwards','(549) 872-0163','ridiculus.mus.proin@outlook.couk','Apr 24, 2022','Enim Incorporated'),
  ('Darrel Hodges','(334) 868-7545','aliquam.ultrices@google.ca','Aug 21, 2022','Sed Nunc Foundation');
```

My desired result after the 2 inserts:

```
myTable (SELECT * FROM myTable):

ID  name
1, 'Samuel Clark'
2, 'Samuel Clark'
3, 'Samuel Clark'
4, 'Faith Hodge'
5, 'Faith Hodge'
6, 'Fuller Hyde'
7, 'Yvonne Edwards'
8, 'Darrel Hodges'

myTableDetails (SELECT * FROM myTableDetails):

myTableID  phone            email                       date          company 
1,         '1-887-516-2723','metus.aenean.sed@yahoo.ca','Apr 9, 2023','Convallis Dolor Ltd'
2,         '1-887-516-2723','metus.aenean.sed@yahoo.ca','Apr 9, 2023','Convallis Dolor Ltd'
3,         '1-887-516-2723','metus.aenean.sed@yahoo.ca','Apr 9, 2023','Convallis Dolor Ltd'
4,         '(903) 877-5281','nunc@aol.com',             'Mar 18, 2023','Eu Foundation'
5,         '(903) 877-5281','nunc@aol.com',             'Mar 18, 2023','Eu Foundation'
6,         '1-886-712-8325','neque.non@hotmail.org',    'Jan 21, 2022','In Tempus Associates'
7,         '(549) 872-0163','ridiculus.mus.proin@outlook.couk','Apr 24, 2022','Enim Incorporated'
8,         '(334) 868-7545','aliquam.ultrices@google.ca','Aug 21, 2022','Sed Nunc Foundation'
```

Comment: Table definitions, sample data and desired output are needed here. This is so obfuscated it is impossible to discern what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange assume all columns are VARCHAR and key columns are INT.

Comment: I'm not going to spend a bunch of time creating dummy tables and dummy data to then spend more time to help you solve your problem. It isn't even clear what you want to do here. Try creating a fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/). At the very least tables and sample data.

Comment: @SeanLange I added the query for sample data above and made some edits. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Can you also show us your desired results - data is worth 1000 words and if I'm honest I can't make sense of what you are asking from the essay.

Comment: @DaleK I added the desired results. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm ¿Is it allowed to create an identity column on `tempImport` (e.g. `rowId`)? just to provide a row identifier on `tempImport` to build the queries to insert into `myTable` using that new identity column (`rowid`) as your `myTable.ID` value ?

Comment: @MauricioOrtega you can use ROW_NUMBER() if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering not using `IDENTITY_INSERT` I suggest this solution:

```
--Retrieve the maximum id ever our identity column incremented to
DECLARE @max_id INT = (SELECT Max(ID) FROM myTable)
IF @max_id IS NULL SET @max_id = 0

--Insertion considering that our ID in identity
INSERT INTO myTable (name)
SELECT name 
FROM tempImport
ORDER BY name, phone, email, date, company

--Insertion into the myTableDetails by joining tempImport and recently inserted rows in myTable
INSERT INTO myTableDetails
SELECT b.ID, a.phone, a.email, a.date, a.company 
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name, phone, email, date, company) row,* 
    FROM tempImport
) a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) row,* 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE ID > @max_id
) b
ON a.row = b.row
```